# How to extract tables from outlook mails

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I need to make a routine in c# that takes an MS outlook email (which will have tables inside it) and extract the tables contents to a txt file or csv file.

I don't really know where to start with this.

Could any body tell me how or where to start with this?

Comment: I don't have any special restrictions, I could use if it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you already figured out how to get the HTML from the email, you can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse it and extract what you need.

You can install the Pack using [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).